# LString will be a linked list class that imitates the standard Java String and StringBuilder classes

Tags: java

I'm having trouble writing a charAt() and seCharAt methods for a linked list object that builds strings. The class, called LString contains a constructor and a few other methods. It runs with another file that tests its ability as a linked list string builder, and I am receiving this error message:
Running constructor, length, toString tests (10 tests)
Starting tests: ..........
Time: 0.032
OK! (10 tests passed.)

Running compareTo and equals tests (18 tests)
Starting tests: ..................
Time: 0.041
OK! (18 tests passed.)

Running charAt and setCharAt tests (18 tests)
Starting tests: ...E.....E.....E..
Time: 0.065

There were 3 failures:
1) t33bTestIndexOutOfBoundsCharAtLength0
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected but was
        ... 2 more

This is what my code looks like.

```
public class LString {

    public class node {
        char data;
        node next;

        public node(char data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public node(char data, node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    node front;

    public LString() {
        this.front = null;
    }

    public LString(String original){
        if (original.length() == 0){
            this.front = null;
        }else{
            front = new node(original.charAt(0));
                node current = front; 
                for(int i = 1; i < original.length(); i ++){
                    current.next = new node(original.charAt(i));
                    current = current.next;
                }
        }
     }   

     // finds length of LString   
     public int length(){
         int length = 0;
         node list = front;
         if (list == null){
             return 0;
         }else{
             while (list != null){
             list = list.next;
             length += 1;
         }
      return length;   
      }           
   }

     // creats a string with the same contents as LString
     public String toString(){
         String word = "";
         for (int c = 0; c < this.length(); c++){
             word = word + charAt(c);
         }
       return word;   
     }

     //compares two LStrings and finds the one that is lexicographically greater 
     public int compareTo(LString anotherLString) {

         int shortString;

         if (this.length() < anotherLString.length()){
             shortString = this.length();
         }else{ 
             shortString = anotherLString.length();
      }

      int difference = 0;

      if(this.length() == 0 && anotherLString.length() > 0){
          return -1;
      }

      if(anotherLString.length() == 0 && this.length() > 0){
          return 1;
      } 

      if(this.length() < anotherLString.length()){
          return -1;
      }

      if(anotherLString.length() < this.length()){
          return 1;
      }     

      for (int j = 0; j < shortString; j++){
          if (this.charAt(j) > anotherLString.charAt(j)){
              difference += 1;
          }else if (this.charAt(j) == anotherLString.charAt(j)){
              difference += 0;
          }else{
              difference -= 1;
          }   
      }   
      return difference;
    }

    //returns true if LString and other have the same characters 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {

        if (other == null || !(other instanceof LString)){
            return false;
        }else {
            LString otherLString = (LString)other;
            if (this.length() != otherLString.length()){
                return false;
        }else{ 
            for (int j = 0; j < otherLString.length(); j++){
                if (this.charAt(j) != otherLString.charAt(j)){
                    return false;
                }   
            }
         }             
      }
      return true;
    }

    //returns the character at index 
    public char charAt(int index){
         if (index < 0 || index > this.length() - 1){
             throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bad index");
         }else{
             node curr = front; 
             for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                 curr = curr.next;
             }
            return curr.data;
         }
    }

    //set character at given index to ch
    public void setCharAt(int index, char ch){
        node curr = front; 
        if (index < 0 || index > this.length() - 1){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bad index");
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            curr = curr.next;
            }
           curr.data = ch;   
        }

    }

    // returns a substring from start to end
    public LString substring(int start, int end){

        String newString = "";
        node curr = front; 

        if (start < 0 || end > this.length() || end < start ){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bad index");
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (i <= start){
            if (i == start){   
                for (int j = start; j < end; j++){
                newString += curr.data;
                curr = curr.next;
            }
         return (new LString(newString));   
         }
         i++;   
         curr = curr.next;      
       }
      return null;   
    }

    //replaces substring with lStr
    public LString replace(int start, int end, LString lStr){
        if (start < 0 || end > this.length() || end < start){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bad index");
        }
        String newString = this.substring(0, start).toString() + lStr.toString() +     
        this.substring(end, this.length()).toString();
        LString newLString = new LString(newString);
        this.front = newLString.front;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Any advice? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you narrow down your problem without posting so much code?

Comment: It's giving me a java.lang.NullPointerException error instead of IndexOutOfBounds on the charAt and setCharAt (you can look at the code for those). I don't know what I'm doing wrong